# How to create and populate dropdowns programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder

I was trying to create dropdowns in using a for loop like this:

```
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //build placeholder
        for(int x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {

            DropDownList dp = new DropDownList();
            dp.ID = "carrirerDp " + x.ToString();
            dp.DataSource = PhoneCarrierSqlDataSource;               
            dp.DataTextField = "carrier_name";
            dp.DataValueField = "crr_id";
            DropDownPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(dp);
            DropDownPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
        }     
    }
```

The Dropdowns are created but they are empty.
Execpt the one I created with asp markup

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="PhoneCarrierDropDownList" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="PhoneCarrierSqlDataSource" DataTextField="carrier_name" 
    DataValueField="crr_id">
 </asp:DropDownList>  

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PhoneCarrierSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * 
                   FROM Table">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And here is the place holder:

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder id="Area1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't databound yet:

```
 dp.DataBind();
```